# Alternate to a proportional linear solenoid

Tags: solenoid

I am trying to build a circuit using gears, motors, and relays only which mimics the motion of a proportional linear solenoid i.e. Hold a spring compressed at a certain distance depending on the current passed, and push/ release it further based on the increase/ decrease of current. The compression and release is quite frequent, something as frequent as one pressing the car clutch while driving.

I am trying to use a cam follower mechanism but it doesnt work out. Can you please help me out in this regard?.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like more of a mechanical engineering question than one of electrical engineering. Tell us what the problems are with the cam follower. This is a common mechanism to use for translation of a rotary motion to linear displacement.

Comment: I want the circuit/ mechanism to hold the spring until the current is reduced/ increased. However with the cam follower, the spring is not held for the duration required i.e. as long as i pass x amps of current the spring should be displaced only by y and stay there... Sorry if i'm not very clear..

Comment: Just curious ... Why not use a proportional linear solenoid? Is this a learning experience or is there some criteria that the solenoid does not meet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use feedback (either linear position or shaft angle) to position the motor shaft with a sego loop. Ideally if you're using the translational position as feedback you'd include the inverse kinematic in the controller. If you're controlling shaft angle you can linearize the response by a similar method.

So the suggestion is- measure the input current (control set point) and control the cam angle either directly or via measuring the resulting translational displacement.

Comment: Can we have a circuit without the cam follower pls

Comment: The circuit is the same if you use a Scotch yoke, a crank or a leadscrew/nut. The point is to use feedback to control servo position.